# Travel alone on accompanied visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I have an accompanied visa with my grandparents but because of some reason they cannot travel with me. I am above 17 years. Can I travel alone and will I be allowed to enter UK as my real aunt puts up there?

Answer (score 5):

If your visa states that you must be accompanied by your grandparents then it is not valid unless you travel with at least one them.  If you want to travel alone you will need to apply for a new visa.

See https://www.gov.uk/standard-visitor-visa/if-youre-under-18 (emphasis added):

> ## Travelling with an adult
>
> When travelling to the UK with an adult (someone over the age of 18), you’ll need to identify them in your visa application.
>
> If the person you’re travelling with isn’t your parent, you’ll need to provide specific information about them in your application.
>
> Their name will appear on your visa, and **you’ll be refused entry to the UK if you arrive in the UK without them.**
>
> You can identify up to 2 adults in your visa application, and **your visa will only be valid if you travel with at least one of them.**

If you want a visa that will allow you to travel alone, you need to prove several things:

> ## Travelling alone
>
> You can travel to the UK without an adult (someone over the age of 18).
>
> Your parent or guardian will need to provide their:
>
> - written consent for you to travel to the UK
> - full contact details
>
> They’ll also need to provide proof that you have somewhere suitable to live during your stay in the UK, including:
>
> - the name and date of birth of the person that you will be staying with
> - an address where you will be living
> - details of your relationship to the person who’ll be looking after you
> - consent in writing so they can look after you during your stay in the UK

It may be possible to amend your existing visa, but I doubt it.  The best way to find out will be to ask at the consulate where you applied for the existing visa.